# How to use differential inequality to establish a bound on variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Given $\frac{dN}{dt} \leq \Lambda-\mu N,$ how can it be shown that $N(t) \leq N(0)e^{-\mu t} + \frac{\Lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu t})?$

I guess a more fundamental question (I've never worked with differential inequalities) is: Do they work the same way as DEs?

Comment: It could be good to read about [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$\frac{dN}{dt} \leq L-u N
$,
$e^{ut}(\frac{dN}{dt}+uN)
\le Le^{ut}
$
or
$\frac{d(e^{ut}N)}{dt}
\le Le^{ut}
$.
Integrating from
$0$ to $x$,
$e^{ut}N(t)\big|_0^x
\le \int_0^x Le^{ut} dt
= \frac{L}{u}e^{ut}\big|_0^x
$
or
$e^{ux}N(x)-N(0)
\le \frac{L}{u}(e^{ux}-1)
$,
or
$N(x)
\le e^{-ux}N(0)+\frac{L}{u}(1-e^{-ux})
$.

Note that it is legal
to *integrate* an inequality,
but not, in general,
to differentiate an inequality.