Prove that $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|=0$
I am reading Paper but I have a difficult in understand the following statement

They proved that $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{d t}\|f\|^2=\frac{1}{2} f^{\prime}\left[G+G^{\prime}\right] f+\Sigma \bar{u}_j f^{\prime} Q_j f \leqslant-\varepsilon\|f\|^2$ for some $\epsilon >0$.

Then, they claim that from that equation, we can obtain $\displaystyle \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|=0$.
I don't know how to obtain $\displaystyle \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|=0$.
My attempt:
Case 1: If $\|f\|=0$, then obviously $\displaystyle \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|=0$.
Case 2: If $\|f\| \ne 0$, then $\frac{1}{2} \dfrac{\frac{d}{dt}\|f\|^2}{\|f\|^2} \le -\epsilon$. Then $\frac{1}{2} \ln \|f\|^2 \le -\epsilon t$  where $t >0$ (I am not pretty sure about that, I took integral two sides). As a result, then $\|f\|^2 \le e^{-2\epsilon t}$. Then $\displaystyle \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|^2=0$.
Could you please help me with checking my work?
p.s: For $Q$ and $u$. I think you don't need to think about it. You just need to use the first and the last equality.
The mapping $f(x,u,r)$ of $E^{m+k} \to E^{m}$.
p.ss: "For some $\epsilon$" means $\exists \epsilon$.

What is $f$, then$Q$, then $u$ ? For some $\epsilon$ means all or $\exists$ ?

Yeah, not nearly enough context here. It certainly isn't true for all $f.$

@EDX yeah,  for some $\epsilon$  means $\exists$

@EDX I think $\epsilon$ denotes epsilon used in a proof.

@ThomasAndrews For $Q$ and $u$. I think you don't need to think about it. You just need to use the first and the last equality.
The mapping $f(x,u,r)$ of $E^{m+k} \to E^{m}$.

Ok man, may you add this in your question so that everyone can answer it properly with the full initial context and hypothesis

I added. Is it ok @EDX

I mean adding the whole context of your problem introducing $Q,U$, what objects are they ? Write it all in your question. ;)

Put it in the question. @Pipnap People,shouldn't have t9 read the comments t9 understand your question.

$|f|^2$ is evidently a differentiable function of $t$ with $\dfrac{d}{dt} |f|^2 \le -\epsilon |f|^2$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, and of course $|f|^2 \ge 0$.  You might look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363580/how-to-use-differential-inequality-to-establish-a-bound-on-variable?noredirect=1

@RobertIsrael Is it different from what I did ?

This is just Gronwall's Lemma which you seem to have applied
